# USPS API doesn't return Priority Mail online rate

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, api, shipping-methods, usps

I'm running Magento Community Edition V1.9.x and offer both FedEx and USPS on my website.  For USPS, I offer the allowed shipping method, Priority Mail on the backend.  On the frontend, this returns the USPS retail price, not the online price.

Does anyone know how I can have Magento request the online price?  The documentation for the USPS V4 API is found here:

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/rate-calculator-api.pdf

On page 5, I see there is a Service Request and things like "All" and "Online" and "Priority Commercial".  I'm guessing one of these is a variable being passed by Magento.  Any idea how this is coded in Magento and what needs to be changed to return the online pricing?  What is the file location?